# Cambiar tres letras por otras 4

Tags: batch

Tengo un archivo que edito con editor de texto de extencion DEF

Al inicio dice

```
DEFBLALALALALALA
askjdhkjsdhakjhdk
asdajkdhsjakhdkjsa
```

**larguisimo hasta 4000 Lineas solo quiero cambiar la primera linea**

quiero que con un Batch me cambie el texto DEF al inicio del Documento y quede el texto como DLL.

Deberia quedar asi:

```
DLLBLALALALALALA
askjdhkjsdhakjhdk
asdajkdhsjakhdkjsa
```

El codigo que tengo me edita la cuarta linea sin modificar el texto en un .ini

```
echo.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set new_line=textoviejo
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (version.ini) do (set "resultado=%%A")&call :sub
copy salida.txt version.ini
del salida.txt
goto:eof
:sub
echo !resultado:nuevotexto=%new_line%!>>salida.txt
goto:eof
```

me gustaria que solo Cambie las 3 primeras letras en sustitucion pero que MANTENGA todo el Contenido anterior.

Comment: Si necesitas que el archivo no se copie durante el proceso de ``REPLACE`` con un batch no lo vas a conseguir, cualquier funcion que utilices necesita copiar el archivo -  renombrarlo - abrirlo - modificarlo y esto se vuelve un problema cuando el archivo es muy grande, te recomiendo utilizar PowerShell para lograr lo que necesitas

Comment: Ummmm powershell esta en todas las versiones de windows?

Comment: PowerShell esta integrado desde windows 7, que version utilizas?

Comment: No importa la version de SO que USO lo que quiero es que me sirva para todos ls windows necesito algo que pueda hacer eso sea el lenguaje que sea es mas si o puedo crear en un bat mejor el programa no es para mi uso personal es para el uso de miles de PCs con diferentes SO amigo

Comment: todos bajo windows claro